# How to get and ignore specific field in JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Game class:

```
public class Game {
  private String name;
  private int steam_appid;
  private boolean isInstalled;
}
```

Json example: https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=435150&filters=basic

My attempt:

```
public static Game readJson(String gameID) throws IOException {
    String targetURL = String.format(STEAM_API, gameID);
    URL url = new URL(targetURL);
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Game json = gson.fromJson(reader, Game.class);
    return json;
}
```

1. When I tried to print the output, I get `Name:null steam_appid:0 isInstalled:false`
2. I want to check the key `success` first, if value is `true` parse it to `Game`. Otherwise, do nothing.
   How can I parse the Json to my `Game`?

Answer (score 0):

If a field is marked **transient**, (by default) it is ignored and not included in the JSON serialization or deserialization.

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects

Comment: How come my `name` is null? I didn't mark transient for that field.

Answer (score 0):

use below code if you don't want to include name in json:

```
public class Game 
{
  private transient String name;
  private int steam_appid;
  private boolean isInstalled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
**Ignore Field at the Field Level**

```
public class Game {
  private String name;

  @JsonIgnore
  private int steam_appid;
  private boolean isInstalled;
}
```

We can also ignore a field directly via the @JsonIgnore annotation directly on the field:

**Option 2:**
In another way you can use **@JsonIgnoreProperties** annotation to skip pojo properties. Here is the code snippet: You can use either way.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "name", "steam_appid" })
public class Game {
  private String name;
  private int steam_appid;
  private boolean isInstalled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response example the class to use `Gson` should look like this:

Note the classes need the getters and setters to be added.

```
class SteamResponseWrapper{
  @SerializedName("434150")
  private SteamResponse steamResponse;
}

class SteamResponse{
  boolean success;
  GameData data;
}

class GameData {
  String name;
  int steam_appid;
  // I couldn't find the isInstalled property if you are adding it, make it transient
}
```

With this structure you would call:
 `SteamResponseWrapper wrapper = new Gson().fromJson(reader, SteamResponseWrapper.class)`
and then
`wrapper.getSteamResponse().isSuccess()`
to check the success field.
And
`wrapper.getSteamResponse().getData()`
to access the game object.

But the problem I see is that the top object name is in fact data and will change for every game. So I don't think Gson will be able to handle this because for every request the annotated serialized name should be different.

I think you will be better of handling it with Jackson or as a JsonObject.

**EDIT I**

This example uses these maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**The example:**

```
public class SteamApiReader {
    private static final String STEAM_API = "http:// ......";
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            SteamApiReader.readJson("435150");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Game readJson(String gameID) throws IOException {
        Game rtn = null;
        String targetURL = String.format(STEAM_API, gameID);;
        URL url = new URL(targetURL);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());

        JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(reader);
        JsonStructure jsonStructure = jsonReader.read();

        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonStructure;
        JsonObject wrapper = jsonObject.getJsonObject(gameID);
        boolean success = wrapper.getBoolean("success");
        if(success) {
            JsonObject data = wrapper.getJsonObject("data");
            String name = data.getString("name");
            int steamAppId = data.getInt("steam_appid");
            rtn =  new Game(name, steamAppId);
        }

        return rtn;
    }

    public static class Game{
        public Game(String name, int steamAppId) {
            this.name = name;
            this.steamAppId = steamAppId;
        }

        String name;
        int steamAppId;
    }

}
```

Comment: I see. Could you give show some hints on how I should go about this

Comment: See the example in Edit I.